# In a spontaneusly broken gauge theory, when is the low energy theory vector-like?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking

In the Standard Model it happens that the surviving unbroken sector, SU(3)xU(1), is vector-like, this is, the left and right representations of the (Weyl) fermions have the same charge and then can be considered as a single Dirac fermion. Lacking better terminology, allow me to call this pair of same-charge representations a "vector-like" representation.

Perhaps this was to be expected in order to allow the higgs field to give mass to the fermions, but it could be a particular case of artful assigment of charges. So question is double-edged:

- If the same higgs field is the mechanism that give mass to [some] fermions of the model, does it implies for sure that such particles will form vector-like representations?
- If we allow for some fermions to remain massless, is there some case where such particles will still be forced to form vector-like representations? (For instance, could it be that the surviving group does not allow for complex representations?).

Comment: Would more standard terminology for this be a "chiral" (non-vector-like) vs. a "non-chiral" (vector-like) theory, or am I misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: @ACuriousMind but I was afraid about creating confusion with perturbative chiral theory etc.

Answer (score 1):

For your first point, I would say that if you want to give a mass term to a Dirac fermion through the Higgs mechanism, you will do it with a Yukawa interaction $\bar \psi H \psi$ which is chiral notation is $H (\bar \psi_L \psi_R + \bar \psi_R \psi_L)$.

Since the Higgs is not charged under the unbroken group, it follows that $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$ are in the same representation.

If some massless fermions are in a chiral representation of the unbroken group, I they will stay in a chiral representation after the Higgs mechanism.